# Equivalnce definition of an Interval Exchange Maps

Tags: analysis, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Interval Translation maps :

Consider the circle $\mathbb{T}^1= \frac{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{Z}}$. We represent it as a union of disjoint subsegments $M_j = [t_j; t_{j+1})$,
$j = 0, \cdots, n, t_0 = t_n$ and define the map $S$ by the formula
\begin{align}
S(t)=t+c_j, \quad \text{mod}1, \quad t\in M_j
\end{align}
Here $c_j$ are real values. Such map is called interval translation (ITM).

Interval Exchange Maps:

In some recent paper its definition is :

> Any one-to-one ITM is called IEM.

The original definition made by Michael Keane (1975):

> Let $X = [0,1) $ and $n \geq 2$ is an integer. For each probability vector $\alpha =(\alpha_1 \cdots \alpha_n )$ with $\alpha_i >0$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$, we set:
> $\beta_0 =0$ and $\beta_i = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{i}\alpha_j$ and $X_i=[\beta_{i-1}, \beta_{i})$.
> Let $\tau$ be a permutation of the symbols ${1, ... , n}$ then $\alpha^{\tau}=(\alpha_{\tau^{-1}(1)} , ..., \alpha_{\tau^{-1}(n)} )$ is a probability vector with positive components, and we can form the corresponding $\beta_{i}^{\tau}$ and $X_{i}^{\tau}$:
> $\beta_{i}^{\tau}=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{i}\alpha_{\tau^{-1}(j)}$ and $X_{i}^{\tau}=[\beta_{i-1}^{\tau},\beta_{i}^{\tau} )$.
> Now define :
> $S: [0,1) \to [0,1)$ where $S(x)= x - \beta_{i-1} + \beta_{\tau(i)-1}^{\tau}$ for each $x \in X_i$. Such map is called Interval Exchange Map or IEM.

Now I want to see why these two different definitions of IEM are equivalent?

Actually I need to see why for every one to one ITM there is a permutation like $\tau$ such that the original definition is concluded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in the second definition of ITM the map $S$ takes $X_i$ to $X^\tau_{\tau(i)}$: this follows immediately from
$$
S(x)= x - \beta_{i-1} + \beta_{\tau(i)-1}^{\tau}.
$$
That is, $$S(X_i)=X^\tau_{\tau(i)}\quad\text{and so}\quad S(X_{\tau^{-1}(i)})=X^\tau_{i}.$$

So, to answer your question, take an IEM that is an ITM according to the first definition. To find an appropriate $\tau$ you just need to consider the images of $X_1,\ldots, X_n$, thus $$S(X_1),\ldots, S(X_n),$$ then *order* them successively on the circle, say $$S(X_{\tau^{-1}(1)})=X^\tau_1,\ldots, S(X_{\tau^{-1}(n)})=X^\tau_n$$ for some permutation $\tau$. This will be precisely your desired permutation.